# returning "non_field_errors": in Postman

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

There is validation in `StorySerializer`, which works fine. In Postman during creating story with 3+ genres it returns

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Max genres: 2"
    ]
}


class StorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ....
    def validate(self, data):
        if len(data['genres']) > 2:
            raise ValidationError('Max genres: 2')
        return data
```

Can I change `non_field_errors` to another name?

Comment: This *is* a field error. You should put that logic in the `validate_genres` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
raise serializers.ValidationError({
    'Max genres': 'Your Custom Message'
})
```